# C++ Register Constexpr Callbacks

Tags: c++, gcc, constexpr

Hi Stackoverflow community,

i have the following requirement:

I want to have a base class called **PeripheralBase** which has a constexpr constructor. Now i want to inherit from this base class with multiple other classes like Adc or Timer.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

class PeripheralBase
{
    public:
        constexpr PeripheralBase()
        {
            registered_cb_[count_cb_++] = this;
        }

        virtual void Callback()
        {

        }

        static void RunCallback()
        {
            for(auto& i : registered_cb_)
            {
                if(i != nullptr)
                {
                    i->Callback();
                }
            }
        }

        static constexpr std::array<PeripheralBase*, 5> registered_cb_ = {nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
        static constexpr int count_cb_ = 0;
};

class Adc : PeripheralBase
{
    public:
        constexpr Adc() 
        {

        }

        void Callback()
        {
            std::cout << "AdcCallback";
        }
};

class Timer : PeripheralBase
{
    public:
        constexpr Timer() 
        {

        }

        void Callback()
        {
            std::cout << "TimerCallback";
        }
};

constexpr Timer tim1;
constexpr Adc adc;

int main ()
{    
    while(1)
    {
        // Should call Adc and Timer callback
        PeripheralBase::RunCallback();
    }
}
```

So i want to create the class instances and there instance pointers at compile time, to call them at runtime.

It is not possible with constexpr member variables.
Is that possible in a different way?

Comment: `registered_cb_[count_cb_++]` is not constexpr.

Comment: `constexpr std::array<const PeripheralBase*, 5> PeripheralBase::registered_cb_{{&tim1, &adc, nullptr, nullptr}};`?

Comment: @Klaus Yeah, i now, but i want to do something similar.

Comment: @Jarod42 I want to create a array with a specific length, all initialized with nullptr's. And if I create for example 2 instances during the compile time, I want the two instance pointers in this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will start with some observations from your code:

You have a kind of container functionality in your Base class. This means, the base class is also containing the element pointers of its own type. For me it is bad design as a container is not the base type itself. For that I personally want to split the container type and the base type of your object hierarchy.

The next point is, that you have on one hand a fixed number of elements given to your `std::array` which is less flexible and also the need of creating all the objects "somewhere".

And as a small reminder: If the object is `constexpr` it is also `const` implicitly which means you have to make your member functions also be `const` if you want to run them for `constexpr` instances.

OK, if we start splitting up the container type and the base class type, we can have something like the following code, but still having all the problems mentioned above:

```
class PeripheralBase
{
    public:
        constexpr PeripheralBase(){}

        virtual void Callback() const {}
};

class Adc : public PeripheralBase
{
    public:
        constexpr Adc() { }
        void Callback() const { std::cout << "AdcCallback"; }
};

class Timer : public PeripheralBase
{
    public:
        constexpr Timer() { }
        void Callback() const { std::cout << "TimerCallback"; }
};

constexpr Timer tim1;
constexpr Adc adc;

class PeripheralContainer
{
    public:
    static constexpr void CallAll()
    {
        for( auto el: registered_cb_ )
        {
            if (el) { el->Callback(); }
        }

    }

    static constexpr std::array<const PeripheralBase*, 5> registered_cb_ = {&adc, &tim1, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
};

int main ()
{
    PeripheralContainer::CallAll();
}
```

If we want to automate the object generating and also looping over all generated elements, we can do it in a simple recursive template class. In every iteration of the class template loop we create a single object and a member function doing something with this object. The complete ( top most ) class template instance itself behaves like the overall container. That results in the following additional code:

```
class PeripheralContainer2;

template < typename FIRST, typename ... REST >
class PeripheralContainer2<FIRST,REST...>: PeripheralContainer2< REST...>
{
    static constexpr FIRST element{};

    public:
    static constexpr void Call( auto callable )
    {
        callable(&element);
        PeripheralContainer2< REST...>::Call( callable );
    }
};

template< >
class PeripheralContainer2<>
{
    public:
    static constexpr void Call( auto ){}
};

int main ()
{
    PeripheralContainer2<Timer, Adc> z;
    z.Call([](const PeripheralBase* p){ p->Callback();});
}
```

If you use `PeripheralContainer2` you have no need to manually create the objects "somewhere", store them and loop over them later. All is done in the template class instance. The template is also not limited to any number of elements, simply provide as many types you like.

Comment: Thank you Klaus vor your detailed answer.

The Problem is, that want to register the class instances throw different compile units. For example:

The PeripheralContainer should be in one compile unit. And the adc instance and the tim1 instance could be in two different compile units. So i want a count mechanism in the base constructor to count the number of instances created at compile time.

Is this possible? Or can only the linker know how many instances there are in the entire project.

Best regards. Tobias

Comment: `std::tuple` and `std::apply([&](auto*...args){ (callable(args), ...); }, tup);` to avoid recursive template.